# Game centre turned based game with different app versions

Tags: ios, game-center

Quick question,

How does Game Center handle different app versions for turn based games? Does it force you to update before you can search for matches or does it match people on the same version even if they are 3 behind or is this sort of behaviour something you have to create yourself.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create this functionality yourself.   For YamSlam and Sumoku I added a version within my data structure.  If my apps encounters a version it doesn't understand it prompts the user to check for an update.

You maybe could use the categories to only pair like version apps and maintain the version of the data for the duration of the game.  But I haven't tried that or thought through all the implications (for example if you attempt to invite a friend on a different version).